# pip install zbarlight fails

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

System and version details:

```
(venv)$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04 
Codename:   trusty
```

here is the python path

```
$ which python/home/ubuntu/www/venv/bin/python

(venv) $ python --version
 Python 2.7.12`

(venv)$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/ubuntu/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

When i try to install it fails with the following error:

```
(venv) $ pip install zbarlight
Collecting zbarlight
Installing collected packages: zbarlight
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/ubuntu/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
File "/home/ubuntu/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/init.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
**kwargs File "/home/ubuntu/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 748, in install
use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
File "/home/ubuntu/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 961, in move_wheel_files
warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
File "/home/ubuntu/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 316, in move_wheel_files
assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: zbarlight .dist-info directory not found
```

Something went wrong with my environment and i can't manage to figure out what. How can i resolve this?

Comment: I'm seen comments of people having the same problem and saying the package was installed despite of the error. Have you tried to use it? Give it a try

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libzbar-dev`, was able to install on Ubuntu 14.04 with pip.

Comment: @Alberto I tried it but library wasn't installed

Comment: @andrew, looks like these packages where installed 
`sudo apt-get install libzbar0 libzbar-dev
libzbar-dev is already the newest version.
libzbar0 is already the newest version.`